# Running a kernel with CUDAfy .NET using OpenCL asynchronously

Tags: visual-studio, asynchronous, opencl

I am trying to make asynchronous kernel calls to my GPGPU using CUDAfy .NET.

When I pass values to the kernel and copy them back to the host, I do not always get the value I expect.

I have a structure Foo with a byte Bar:

```
[Cudafy]
public struct Foo {
    public byte Bar;
}
```

And I have a kernel I want to call:

```
[Cudafy]
public static void simulation(GThread thread, Foo[] f)
{
    f[0].Bar = 3;
    thread.SyncThreads();
}
```

I have a single thread with streamID = 1 (I tried using multiple threads, and noticed the issue. Reducing to a single thread didn't seem to fix the issue though).

```
        //allocate
        streamID = 1;
        count = 1;
        gpu.CreateStream(streamID);
        Foo[] sF = new Foo[count];
        IntPtr hF = gpu.HostAllocate<Foo>(count);
        Foo[] dF = gpu.Allocate<Foo>(sF);
        while (true)
        {
            //set value
            sF[0].Bar = 1;

            byte begin = sF[0].Bar;

            //host -> pinned
            GPGPU.CopyOnHost<Foo>(sF, 0, hF, 0, count);

            sF[0].Bar = 2;

            lock (gpu)
            {
                //pinned -> device
                gpu.CopyToDeviceAsync<Foo>(hF, 0, dF, 0, count, streamID);
                //run
                gpu.Launch().simulation(dF);
                //device -> pinned
                gpu.CopyFromDeviceAsync<Foo>(dF, 0, hF, 0, count, streamID);
            }
            //WAIT
            gpu.SynchronizeStream(streamID);


            //pinned -> host
            GPGPU.CopyOnHost<Foo>(hF, 0, sF, 0, count);

            byte end = sF[0].Bar;
        }
        //de-allocate
        gpu.Free(dF);
        gpu.HostFree(hF);
        gpu.DestroyStream(streamID);
```

First I create a stream on the GPU.

I am creating a regular structure Foo array of size 1 (sF) and setting it's Bar value to 1. Then I create pinned memory on the host (hF) for Foo as well. I also create memory on the device for Foo (dF).

I initialize the structure's Bar value to 1 then I copy it to the pinned memory (As a check, I set the value to 2 for the structure after copying to pinned, you'll see why later). Then I use a lock to ensure I have full access to the GPU and I queue a copy to dF, a run for the kernel, and a copy from dF. At this point I don't know when this will all actually run on the GPU... so I can call SynchronizeStream to wait on the host until the device is done.

When it's done, I can copy the pinned memory (hF) to the shared memory (sF). When I get the value, it's usually a 3 (which was set on the device) or a 1 (which means either the value wasn't set in the kernel, or the new value wasn't copied to the pinned memory). I do know that the pinned memory is copied to the structure because the structure never has the value of 2.

Over many runs, a small percentage is runs results in something other than begin=1 and end=3. It would always be begin=1, end=1 and it happens about 5-10% of the time.

I have no idea why this happens. I know it generally highlights a race condition, but by calling the sync calls, I would expect the async calls to work in a predictable fashion.

Why would I be encountering this kind of issue with this code?

Thank you so much!

-Phil

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the issue that was occurring. While the launch was being done asynchronously... I didn't include the stream for the launch.

Changing my launch to be:

gpu.Launch(gridsize,blocksize,streamID).simulation(dF);

resolved the problem. It seems that the launches were occurring on stream 0 and the stream 1 and 2 were being synced. So sometimes the data gets set, sometimes it doesn't. A race condition.